# angularjs textbox and back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have input text box

```
 <input id="search-input" class="search-field" ng-trim="false" ng-model="searchData" type="text" maxlength="130" placeholder="Look up product" />
```

On pressing back and forward buttons in browser, the value entered by user before pressing the back/forward buttons remains. I want that value to change as entered on previous page (just like it happens in google search).
On browser back/forward button I see following in inspector:

```
<input id="search-input" class="search-field ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" ng-trim="false" ng-model="searchData" type="text" maxlength="130" placeholder="Look up product" style="">
```

So ng-dirty and ng-touched are trying to tell me that back button has been pressed and value now being shown is not as per back button state. But I need that old value in text box.

Note: I have added a watch for this text box:

```
$scope.$watch('searchData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (!newValue || newValue == "") {
        $('#clear-submit').hide();
    } else {
        $('#clear-submit').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery with angular to show and hide the button?

Comment: Agreed with _WayneEllery_, you can use `ng-show` for this.

Comment: Can you please provide a Plunkr with the issue. When I created a test it did not behave as you have stated: [Test Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/toIt6BteaJkucLhf8OMC?p=preview)

Comment: @WayneEllery  in the URL http://plnkr.co/edit/toIt6BteaJkucLhf8OMC?p=preview   1) enter something in text box, 2) click b 3) Click browser back button 4) Th text box is not maintaining its state with the text you had entered in step 1

Comment: It's not for me. What browser are you using. I tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Comment: pls check this URL http://plnkr.co/edit/CvgrHbrcK891xeBXLJ3i?p=preview and the steps 1) enter something in text box, 2) click b 3) Click browser back button 4) Th text box is not maintaining its state with the text you had entered in step 1